# how HTML/CSS box,gradient fixed background and link to other html

Tags: html, css

I'm doing my networking assignment, but here is some question about the assignment

The assignment need me to make the website as
1.A yellow gradient fixed background.
2.The contents are surrounded by box with grey border.
3.Link up two Web pages with a navigator bar at top of the contents.

for the first requirement, I really don't know how to do it.
and the second requirement, I try to use html class with the css to do it
but the result is fail also, can you tell me how to do it? And I can't make the box surrounded the content, where should I put the code of it?

and the final requirement, I try to use XXX, but after I apply it, I found that I can't click the link of it and move to XXX.HTML
where does it wrong?

And moreover, are these three requirement can only do by CSS? Can I only use html code without CSS to do it?
Thank you

Comment: I posted an answer but then deleted it. This type of question is not worth answering

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

HTML

```
<div class="content"><a href="#">link1</a><br> content 1</div>
<div class="content"><a href="#">link2</a><br> content 2</div>
<div class="content"><a href="#">link3</a><br> content 3</div>
<div class="content"><a href="#">link4</a><br> content 4</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, black);
}

.content{
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGBvNg)